# How do I read the column properties of tables in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've read through the [documentation for Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model) and I see how to use define, but I don't see how I can read the type/allowNull/primaryKey/autoIncrement properties from the Sequelize definition. This is part of my file generated by [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto);

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('account', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    parent_account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'account',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    master_account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'account',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticing the structure of models and modelManager:

```
models: { user: user },
modelManager: ModelManager { models: [ user ], sequelize: [Circular] },
```

I figured that it wasn't expanding user since the object must be too big, so I tried:

```
var userDefinition = this.orm["modelManager"].getModel("user");
if (userDefinition.attributes.id.type.key == "BIGINT") ...
```

`[]` must be used in TypeScript since modelManager is not initialized at compile-time.